# OpenCV C++ error using cvSaveImage Error:Assertion failed ((flags & FIXED_TYPE) != 0) in cv::_InputArray::type

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Im relativly new to OpenCV. In this case I tried to save an image using cvSaveImage after making some processing, but this error was thrown

> Assertion failed ((flags & FIXED_TYPE) != 0) in cv::_InputArray::type, file C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix_wrap.cpp, line 807

It seems, like it has some problem with type of input array, but i have no idea why?.

Here is what my code look like

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("HOLES_CAM1_NG.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    IplImage* houghImg = cvCloneImage(img);

/*

    SOME PROCESSING

                      */

    cvSaveImage("HOLES_CAM1_NG_processed.png", houghImg);


    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    cvReleaseImage(&houghImg);
}
```

Comment: You claim to be using C++, so please, use the C++ OpenCV API, instead of the ancient, deprecated C API. One of the benefits will be not having to juggle raw pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the deprecated C API.

Please try doing something like this:
Reference: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/load_save_image/load_save_image.html

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
 Mat img;
 img = imread( "HOLES_CAM1_NG.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );

 if(!img.data )
 {
   printf( " No image data \n " );
   return -1;
 }
/*

SOME PROCESSING

                  */
 imwrite( "HOLES_CAM1_NG_processed.png", houghImg );

 namedWindow( "Original image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
 namedWindow( "Gray image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

 imshow( "Original image", img );
 imshow( "Hough image", houghImg );

 waitKey(0);

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If cvSaveImage() is not working, it would have been better to remove it like cvCopyImage :)